# western digital caviar black. EXT4-fs error

Tags: linux, ext4, hard-drive

Recently I update my HDD on desktop machine, and bought WD Caviar Black.
But after I format & copy information to it (using dd), and fix partitions size: I have next errors in `kern.log`:

```
Aug 27 16:04:35 home-spb kernel: [148265.326264] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 9054, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:07:11 home-spb kernel: [148421.493483] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 9045, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:17 home-spb kernel: [148546.481693] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10299, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:17 home-spb kernel: [148546.487147] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.258711] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4345, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.277591] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.278202] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4344, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.284760] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.291983] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 9051, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.297495] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.297916] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 9050, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.297940] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.303213] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4425, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.312127] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.312487] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4424, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.317858] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.322231] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4336, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.326250] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.326599] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 4335, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.332397] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.341957] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 5764, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.350709] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.351127] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 5763, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:42 home-spb kernel: [148572.355916] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.401055] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10063, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.404357] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.414699] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 10073, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.420411] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.493933] EXT4-fs error (device sdc2): ext4_mb_generate_buddy:739: group 9059, 32254 clusters in bitmap, 32258 in gd
Aug 27 16:09:43 home-spb kernel: [148572.493956] JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sdc2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
```

One time, machine rebooted (not manually), when I turn it on, it runs `fsck` on `/dev/sdc2` and fix some errors and some files are missing on `/dev/sdc2`

I'v check /dev/sdc2 for badblocks, it doesn't have it ( using `e2fsck -c /dev/sdc2` )
Here is the output of fsck http://pastebin.com/D5LmLVBY

**What else I can do to understand what's wrong here?**

BTW for `/dev/sdc1` no message like that, in `kern.log`

```
Linux version: 3.3.0
Distributive: Debian wheezy
```

Comment: Please show smartctl -a /dev/sdc

Comment: @Spacedust, thanks for helping, I'v already fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in linux 3.3.
The upstream fix is commit [b0dd6b70f0fda17ae9762fbb72d98e40a4f66556](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=b0dd6b70f0fda17ae9762fbb72d98e40a4f66556).

This problem can be reproduced via:

```
        mke2fs -q -t ext4 -O ^flex_bg /dev/vdd 5g
        mount -t ext4 /dev/vdd /mnt
        fallocate -l 4600m /mnt/test
```

More info at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fa.linux.kernel/YzaFr9nWKMs/lQrMh05yP-gJ

Comment: I got the same problem on CentOS 5.8 and kernel 2.6.18-308.13.1.el5